# Can't Run Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Cant Run Flutter Project via Android Device

```
E:\pro67\sample>flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                                 \
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.                                                                                                     Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: d2c5927ef8c4aebb)
Initializing gradle...                                                                                                                                                                                            \Crash report written to E:\pro67\sample\flutter_01.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `flutter doctor` and check whether if you have installed flutter correctly

Answer (score 0):

As shayan suggested you should run `flutter doctor`, if the application continues to crash on start you should inspect Logcat as this is where all android system logs are streamed to.